# How can you parse NON wellformed JSON (maybe using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Is there a way to parse NON wellformed JSON, other than using `eval`?

The background is, that I'm using data tag values to draw a graph like this:

```
<div id="data" data-idata="[1,2,3]" data-sdata="['foo','bar','baz']"></div>
```

This works flawlessly with numeric values, these values are delivered as an array directly in jQuery data, no need to parse JSON here.

However, for the labels a string array is to be passed. `eval` can parse the string in `sdata` just fine, but `JSON.parse` and `jQuery.parseJSON` fail, because it's not wellformed JSON.

```
var $data = $("#data").data(),
    values;

// use eval
out("#out", eval($data.sdata)); // works...

// use JSON.parse
try
{
    values = JSON.parse($data.sdata);
} catch(e) {
    // silent catch
}
out("#out1", values); // values is undefined
```

I put together a [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4b374/1/) to check the thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get error because `['foo','bar','baz']` contains single-quotation marks. [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) specifies that `string` should be enclosed in *double-quotation* marks.

There could be a few work-arounds.

Switch quotation marks in the `data-` attributes:

```
<tag data-sdata='["foo","bar","baz"]' />
```

Or replace in Javascript:

```
values = JSON.parse($data.sdata.replace("'","\""));
```

Comment: Punctual punctuation, one of the pitfalls of javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse. Simply use `.data()`, the function does it for you.

I have changed your HTML, I have swapped quotes in line `data-sdata="['foo', 'bar', 'baz']"` as JSON should use in double-quotation(`"`) marks.

*HTML*

```
<div id="data" data-idata="[1,2,3]" data-sdata='["foo", "bar", "baz"]'></div>
```

*Script*

```
out("#out1", $("#data").data('idata'));
out("#out2", $("#data").data('sdata'));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EE4yw/)

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you cannot easy parse corrupted data for 100% this goes for any data-formats and not only JSON.

If the reason the data are malformed are always the same you should fix it with some str_find and replacement functions.

If it is irregular you have no real chance except writing a really intelligenz and big algorithm. The best way here would be to try to extract the real raw data out of the corrupted string and build a real JSON string with valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try

html

```
<div id="data" data-idata="[1,2,3]" data-sdata='["foo","bar","baz"]'></div>
<div id="out1">out1</div>
<div id="out2">out2</div>
```

js

```
$(function () {
    var out = function (outputId, elem, dataId) {
        return $.each(JSON.parse($(elem).get(0).dataset["" + dataId])
          , function (index, value) {
            $("<ul>").html("<li>" + index + " -> " + value + "</li>")
              .appendTo(outputId);
        });
    };
    out("#out1", "#data", "idata");
    out("#out2", "#data", "sdata");
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/4mJBp/