# How can I get `data-value` using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get `data-value` country using jQuery? I need this in variable:

```
var country = ...;
```

HTML:

```
<a id="obj-details" data-value="{city:'berlin', street: 'mozart', postal_code: '55555', country: 'DE'}">test</a>
```

Comment: `jquery.data('value')`

Comment: `$('#obj-details').data('value')`

Comment: Find detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753629/jquery-get-html-5-data-attributes-with-hyphens-and-case-sensitivity

Comment: @user3266909, please check my answer. this gives you country value as DE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To read `data-value` attribute use below jQuery :

```
$("#obj-details").data('value');
```

and to read `country` from the `data-value` use below jQuery :

```
 var value = $("#obj-details").data('value');
 var obj = eval('(' +value + ')');

 var country = obj.country;
 alert(country );
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9aXYc/39/)**

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
$("#obj-details").attr('data-value');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#obj-details').data('value');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you looking the return data as a object, try like below.

```
var country = eval('(' + $("#obj-details").attr('data-value') + ')');

alert(country.city);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.data(key)` to retrieve that value,

```
var obj = JSON.parse($("#obj-details").data('value')); //Entire object
var country = obj.country; //Country value
```

Comment: `alert(obj);` works fine but `alert(obj.country);`not. It displays `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

jquery.parseJSON(jquery("#obj-details").attr("data-value"));

Answer (score 0):

Try `object` at `data-*` attribute utilizing double `""` quotation marks.

html

```
<a id="obj-details" 
   data-value='{"city":"berlin"
                , "street": "mozart"
                , "postal_code": "55555"
                , "country": "DE"
               }'>test</a>
```

js

```
var obj = JSON.parse($("#obj-details")[0].dataset.value);
var country = obj.country;
$("#obj-details").text(country);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/6LcfS/

See also [How can you parse NON wellformed JSON (maybe using jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24568487/how-can-you-parse-non-wellformed-json-maybe-using-jquery/24570073#24570073)